# Is the RouteValueDictionary class's keys case-insensitive?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routevalues

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) states that it "Represents a **case-insensitive** collection of key/value pairs that you use in various places in the routing framework, such as when you define the default values for a route or when you generate a URL that is based on a route."

From what I can see, it uses a normal `Dictionary<string,object>` to store it's keys internally, so it's actually case-sensitive.  I cannot find any aspect of this class that's case-insensitive, so is the documentation just wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your statement that using `Dictionary<string, object>` makes the comparison case-sensitive is incorrect. `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` allows for a custom `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` implementation to be provided into the constructor. `RouteValueDictionary` does exactly that and passes `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to `Dictionary<string, object>` constructor:

```
public class RouteValueDictionary : IDictionary<string, object> {
    private Dictionary<string, object> _dictionary;

    public RouteValueDictionary() {
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public RouteValueDictionary(object values) {
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        AddValues(values);
    }

    public RouteValueDictionary(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary) {
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>(dictionary, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
```

So to answer the question: **`RouteValueDictionary` is case-insensitive.**

See the code on sourceof.net: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Routing/RouteValueDictionary.cs,551a423c96bb6648